# Concatenate string on a loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

I have a loop hash data.

```
var rec = { };
for (var b = 0; b < 2;b++) {
    rec['id'+b] = b</p>
}
```

Then I have a javascript that create an template.

```
var template ='<table><tr>'
template +='<th class="id"><b>ID</b></th>'
template +='</tr>'
template +='<% for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){ %>' 
template +='<tr><td><%= id+i %></td></tr>'
template +='<% } %>'
template +='</table>';
```

Can somebody help me how to concatenate my string. And how to use the <% %> 
in javascript. I try to copy my code here. But im getting error

Thank you

Comment: i have a loop hash data.
`           var rec = {                       };           `
`            for   (var  b = 0; b < 2;b++)          {              `
  `         rec['id'+b] = b</p>  `
`      }      `

then i have a javascript that create an template.

var template ='<table><tr>'
 template +='<th class="id"><b>ID</b></th>'
    template +='</tr>'
    template +='<% for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){ %>'
    template +='<tr><td><%= id+i %></td></tr>'
    template +='<% } %>'
    template +='</table>';

    i try this approach but it doesnt work. Ca somebody help me to my problem.

Comment: i have a loop hash data.
var rec = {};        
   for   (var  b = 0; b < 2;b++){            
       rec['id'+b] = b;
   }     

then i have a javascript that create an template.

var template ='<table><tr>'
 template +='<th class="id"><b>ID</b></th>'
    template +='</tr>'
    template +='<% for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){ %>'
    template +='<tr><td><%= id+i %></td></tr>'
    template +='<% } %>'
    template +='</table>';

    i try this approach but it doesnt work. Ca somebody help me to my problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there, not in the comments! Format the code with the `{}` button.

Comment: put `;` semicolon at the end of each line

Comment: @Xufox I can edit, always error

Comment: When i try this code<%= id+i %> it doesnt work. Empty, But when i try to hardcode <%= id0 %> it work. Where's is my problem?

Comment: ```<% %>``` isn't working for me at all, so i can't try it out, but what if you put it like ```<%= (id + i) %>```?

Comment: @Thalsan I doesnt work too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        var s = "";
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            s+="what you want to add";
        }
```

and for your case you can this

```
        var template ='<table><tr>';
        template +='<th class="id"><b>ID</b></th>';
        template +='</tr>';
        var tempConcat = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        tempConcat += '<tr><td>'+(id+i)+'</td></tr>';
        }

        template +=tempConcat +'</table>';
```

Comment: I have a hash object;

Comment: var oRec = {};
   ;for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
           oRec['id'+i] = i;
        }

Comment: var template ='<table><tr>'
 template +='<th class="id"><b>ID</b></th>'
 template +='</tr>'
 template +='<tr>'
 template +='</tr>'
    template +='<% for(var i = 0; i < sizeOfObject ; i++){ %>'
    template +='<tr><td><%= id+i%></td></tr>'
    template +='<% } %>'
    template +='</table>';
 
 When i try to print out the value using <%= id+i %>. It doesnt work. But when i hardcoed it <%= id0 %>. It display

Answer (score 0):

to concatenate in javascript you need to use the addition symbol (+).

Example:

var a = 'hello ',
    b = 'my brother';

console.log(a + b);

will result in

hello my brother

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but your use of `+=` is fine for concat. Just modify your for loop a bit.

**HTML**

```
<div id="temp"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var rec = { };
for (var b = 0; b < 2;b++) {
    rec['id'+b] = b;
}

var template ='<table>' + 
                '<tr><th class="id"><b>ID</b></th></tr>';
for (var i in rec) {
    template += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + rec[i] + '</td></tr>';
}    
template +='</table>';

document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = template;
```

**JSFiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6p4afu7/)

Comment: my problem is this line<%= id+i %>. it doesnt concate and print out